# Can I export a video editor timeline to .xml or .aal?

Tags: video

I'm wondering if we can make an edit with several clips, like any video editor, then e**xport the timeline to a .xml or .aaf file**, like the major editor like Final Cut Pro, Adobe Premiere or Sony Vegas. The file describes the edit (cue points, which clip goes where, etc.) but does not include the orignal clips used in the edit).

The point is not to render to a sequence or a clip. It's to import the edit to another software like DaVinci Resolve for color grading, relink the edit information with the source clips and finalizing the edit.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do that. But If you are going to finish in Resolve, you might as well use it for editing too.

Comment: To fcpxml?   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FinalCutProX/Reference/FinalCutProXXMLFormat/StoryElements/StoryElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011227-CH13-SW16  Could you provide a  screenshot of a VSE setup as well as the fcpxml  of the expected result (export from FCP).

Comment: Nope. The job is not done yet. The editing will be done in another PC not strong enough to sustain Resolve. So I think I'll forget Blender for that. Used Premiere, export and import into Resolve.  -  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Blender still lives in an island with no proper support for time code, metadata and edit lists... you might find this interesting: https://github.com/sobotka/Blender-NLE-NextGen/wiki/Blender-NLE-NextGen

Comment: Nice enlightment, thanks. Blender is not yet close enough to the standard of industry. Maybe it don't have to be.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a script to export Davinci Resolve friendly EDL files: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?418606-EDL-export-script-help-needed!

Comment: Good news like any addition to Blender.

Comment: I really hope there is progress with this possible exporter.